# SQL Query to retrieve date adds time to value?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Having a bit of trouble with my SQL query.

I am retrieving a value from my SQL database, where it has the date of when a person was added as a life member. The column type is "date" rather than varchar as i couldnt organise by date if it was just a string.

The value of "DateInducted" is just a simple date such as "01/05/1963"

In the query builder for Visual Studio, I have tested my SQL Statement (which is below) and appears exactly as i want

```
"SELECT [DateInducted], [Name] FROM [LifeMembers] ORDER BY [DateInducted] DESC"
```

However when the Website is loaded, the value is

```
5/26/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Where is it getting the time from? Is there a way to stop this? All i need is the date.

Thinking this is just a simple oversight on my part, but Google searches didnt provide the correct answer. According to W3 schools site, Date type should just give me the date?

Thanks in Advance

Edit:
Page Code now attached

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<h2>Lifemembers</h2>
<table class="DataTable">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptLifemembers" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsLifeMembers">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr class="DataTableHeader">
                <td style="min-width:40%"><strong>Date Inducted</strong></td>
                <td style="min-width:60%"><strong>Member</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="DataTableRow">
                <td style="min-width:40%"><strong><%#Eval("DateInducted")%></strong></td>
                <td style="min-width:60%"><%#Eval("Name")%></td>                
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsLifeMembers" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SPEEDWAYConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [DateInducted], [Name] FROM [LifeMembers] ORDER BY [DateInducted1] DESC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: you'd have to show your asp output code. a date field in a db won't have a time value. it'd have to be a datetime, or somehow getting cast to a datetime

Comment: It is almost certainly a formatting issue in the front end. Change the display format and you will be good to go.

Comment: [This may help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The Sql Date is likely certainly being loaded as a .Net `DateTime`. Use [formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) on your page to control the output.

Comment: Have just added the ASP page code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a format string to your binding expression:

`<%#Eval("DateInducted", "{0:d}")%>`

The `datetime` data type in SQL and the `Date` type in CLR always hold both a date and a time.  In order to display one or the other and not both when converting to string, you need to use a format string or `Date` built-in string conversion functions such as `ToShortDateString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either convert the date to varchar in the query or format the output in asp.net.

If you choose to do it in the query you can use the function Convert:

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50),[DateInducted], 101) DateInducted, [Name] FROM [LifeMembers] ORDER BY [DateInducted] DESC

Comment: FYI "101" is the output "style" depending on data type.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx
Personally I think it is cleaner to convert values for display on the page or as close to presentation layer as practical.